# void method testing javascript

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a method written in javascript and I am using Jasmine to test the method.
The method is a void type which is invoking another method .

I have to test if the method is invoking the other method, the present method is  returning void.

what should I write in the expect clause to compare it.

```
sendMessage=function(data){
if(data!=null)
 {
  postMessage(data);
 }
}
```

Jasmine code :

```
describe('unit test void method', function(){
    it("sendMessage method should invoke the postMessage", function () {
           expect(sendMessage("hello");
    }) 
})
```

what should I compare it with ?

Comment: :D A sample will be more useful.

Comment: A void method should be used to ask an object to do something to itself (change its state) or issuing a notifaction without expecting a response. If it's the former you can check that whatever change has been made to the target object once the function has been run. If it's the latter and just an information method then you wouldn't usually unit test that as it doesn't really affect anything that you can test. If it's something else, are you using void correctly?

Answer (score 6):

James is right. That's a spy function, although I use another approach.

Somewhere in your setup beforeEach function:

```
spyOn(YourObject, 'postMessage').and.callThrough();
```

`YourObject` being whatever object contains the function.

Expectations:

```
it('expects postMessage() to have been called', function () {

    // make the call to this function
    YourObject.postMessage();

    // Check internal function
    expect(YourObject.postMessage).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: It should be  YourObject.postMessage(); instead of YourObject.sendMessage();

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use [Jasmine spies](https://daveceddia.com/jasmine-2-spy-cheat-sheet/) to track when and how often a method is called:

```
expect(obj.method.calls.any()).toBe(true);
```