# How to test void method in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to test some code with void method. I have code like this, I am very confused with test, I didn't have idea with this test. I make test with Jasmine and Karma

```
getMenu(): void {
    this.service.getMenuItems()
    .subscribe(navigation => {
      this.navigationModel = navigation.menu;
    });
  }
```

This is the code. How I can test this code. I have search all with the same problem but I didn't understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [void method testing javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402812/void-method-testing-javascript)

Comment: i cant with javascript but with typescript

Comment: spyOn getMenuItems of your service and check whether it is called.

Answer (score 0):

You would ideally have the actual function tested `this.service.getMenuItems()` in the Service test. In which case, you can just mock the function response and spy on the service function.
All you need to do is, check that your `navigationModel` has a value which is the value returned by your methodSpy.

Example:

```
const mockData = { navigationMenu: [.....]};
//inside beforeEach
 const service= TestBed.get(NavigationService);
    spyOn(service, 'getMenuItems').and.returnValue(
          mockData.navigationMenu
        );
```

Comment: when i test that in sonarqube... that code not cover

Comment: Are you sure the function is being called from somewhere and that, the function calling `getMenu` is called as well