# How to test empty function in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am creating a tooling module in typescript and I have a parent class BaseTool and multiple child classes like ToolA and ToolB.

In BaseTool class most of the methods are protected and child classes are overriding them.

Code BaseTool class:

```
Class BaseTool {

protected doSelection() {
 //some code
}
}
```

Code ToolA class (This is a read-only class):

```
Class ToolA extends BaseTool {

protected doSelection() {} //<-- This function must be empty, and i don't know, how to test?
}
```

Code ToolB class (This is another class with function definition):

```
Class ToolB extends BaseTool {

protected doSelection() {
//super()
//code
} //<-- This function is not empty and i write all the desired test cases (no problem here)
}
```

How can I write test cases for read-only class (ToolA) protected methods with no body?

Comment: If you have access to the function in your test you could call `Function.prototype.toString()` and check that the function body is empty.

Comment: I think we need to understand the meaning of `TDD`. How you can test a function which is not returning anything. TDD helps to check wheather a function returning the desired result or not

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36402812/5108695 this problem is a bit related to yours ! have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a utility function to test an empty function as suggested in comments using `Function.prototype.toString()`

```js
function isEmpty(f) {
    // Get content between first { and last }
    const m = f.toString().match(/\{([\s\S]*)\}/m);
    // Strip comments
    const l = m && m[1].replace(/^\s*\/\/.*$/mg, '').trim();
    if (l.length === 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};

function doSeatMouseClick(_event, _seat) { 
 //do nothing, read only
}

var bool = isEmpty(doSeatMouseClick);
console.log(bool)
```

Answer (score -1):

use the same reference to the same empty function.
var emptyFunction = function {};
and then use
vm.emptyFunction = angular.isFunction(callback) ? callback : emptyFunction;
Then test
expect(vm.emptyFunction).toEqual(emptyFunction);